# PowerMock mocking private methods with limited data access

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I'm trying to mock private methods via PowerMock, but in my expectPrivate method, I do not have all the arguments that my unit test has access to (some of the arguments are created within the method that is calling this private method). Thus, when I need to fill expectPrivate method field, I am unable to do so and my unit test doesn't work. Is there any way to get around this?

Thanks

**EDIT: Sorry about my terrible explanation. I have written some code to demonstrate what I mean.**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
public class FooTest
{
    @Test
    public void testFoobar() throws Exception{
        Foo x = new Foo("hi");

        PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Foo.class, "foobar2");
        Method[] methods = MemberMatcher.methods(Foo.class, "foobar2");

        PowerMock.expectPrivate(Foo.class, methods[0], x).andReturn("hi");

        PowerMock.replay(Foo.class);

        Foo.foobar("hi");

    }
}
```

and

```
public class Foo
{
    public String name;
    public Foo(String aString){
       name = aString;
    }

    public static String foobar(String aString){

        Foo aFoo = new Foo("hi");

        aString = aString + foobar2(aFoo);

        return aString + " blah";
    }

    private static String foobar2(Foo aFoo){
        return "hi" + aFoo.name;
    }
}
```

I can't mock the foobar2 method because I cannot recreate that Foo aFoo the foobar method created. It will give me an error saying my object I created for the testing is not the same one as the one that went into the private method.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Showing code is always a plus as well.

Comment: Like, the parameters to use expectPrivate expects arguments of the method it is mocking right? I just do not have access to those arguments. Like for example I'm mocking method foobar(obj x, obj y) as part of the foo class, I can't fill my parameters expectPrivate(foo.class, "foobar", x, y) since I do not have access to objects x and y in my unit test method

Comment: Well why don't you have access the objects you're intending to mock with?

Comment: Because the foo method creates objects x and y

Comment: Yes but the point of mocking is that you pass *mock* objects, so it is irrelevant whether `foo` creates them normally. Is your code not tailored to be unit tested via mocking?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, I have updated OP. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly do have access to the arguments created inside the method calling the private method. You need to have the constructors return mock objects. See http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor.

Comment: I have updated OP. Sorry, my original question was not very clear.

Comment: Your update doesn't change my answer. If you mock the constructor to return a mocked Foo then the first line of the foobar method will obtain your mocked Foo. When you mock the call to foobar2, you will know that your mocked Foo is being passed.